# How to interpret result of kppm modelling from spatstat

Tags: r, statistics, spatial, spatstat

I am recently using spatstat to do a bit of spatial data analysis. I am now really struggling to interpret the result of kppm models. For example, when I fit a log-gaussian cox model, what does the parameter trend, alpha, sigma2, mu and theta mean? I tried to find some relevant stuff online but failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which model you fitted. If you just specified `kppm(X~1, "LGCP")` where `X` is your data point pattern, then:

- `trend` is the estimated intensity (expected number of points per unit area). In this case it is just equal to the average intensity of your data.
- `mu` is the mean of the log of the driving random intensity.
- `sigma2` is the variance of the log of the driving random intensity. In some sense this measures the strength of clustering.
- `alpha` is the correlation scale in the exponential covariance, `C(r) = sigma2 * exp(-r/alpha)` of the driving random intensity. In some sense this measures the scale of clustering.

For further details and explanation see Chapter 12 of [the spatstat book](http://book.spatstat.org)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can provide a reproducible example to fix ideas. Maybe fit a LGCP model to a built-in dataset and show both the code to fit the model and the result of printing the model, so we can see the resulting estimates. The best reference for details about spatstat functionality is the [spatstat book](https://book.spatstat.org). Chapter 12 contains all the details about cluster models (including LGCP models).